# What is the difference between moving "across" and "through" an area?

Tags: prepositions

> Tom and his friends were on an island.
> They walked through the island.
> They listened and then ran across the island to look down the river.

What is the difference between *through* and *across* in this text?
The island is a three dimensional space, so why does it use *across* to express movement to the river?

Comment: It's usual to speak of travelling _across_ a piece of land, regarding it as a two-dimensional surface.

Comment: The use of *through* is similar to [Lexico sense 1.2](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/through), suggesting a thorough exploration. What did your own research find?

Comment: [This question is related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218654/walk-across-through-on-the-crosswalk) as is [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476870/a-trajectory-along-vs-across-vs-through-three-points)

Comment: The second one seems strange by itself. *Through the jungle, through the village, through the area* even, but *through the island*…is harder to imagine, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can *walk through a park, garden, wilderness,* maybe even *parking lot*, but not through an island. I guess it's just a question of what usage sounds most natural given the verb and noun on either side. Maybe in this context *walk through* implies getting to the other side, and if you walked through an island you'd end up in the sea.

Comment: @StuartF I think it's because of the idea of containment or confinement involved in "through". Gardens, parks, car parks and even wildernesses have boundaries which you can cross to enter or leave them, an island only has its coastline. This means that an island is an entity rather than a defined space and the idea of walking _through_ it suggests, to me, that there is a tunnel or cave system leading through the rock of the island. We do talk about "walking through the mountains" but that suggests that we are keeping to the valleys and that the mountains are "containing" us as we do so.

Answer (score 4):

*Across* is two-dimensional -- it refers to a motion over landscape or flat area. *Crossing* the area is going from one side to the other, which assumes boundaries on the area.

*Through* is three-dimensional -- it refers to a motion that may move in only two dimensions, but which counters obstacles in three dimensions.

Contrast walking across the park and through the park, or across the river and through the river, or across the woods and through the woods.

As for why you can't walk through the island, *island* is simply not a three-dimensional word. It refers to a bounded island surface surrounded by non-island surface, and there's no third dimension to refer to.

Comment: Yes - across a field, but through a forest. Re island - I guess if it were the island of Manhattan, or the island of Singapore - you could walk "through" it - as there is plenty of third dimension there.

Answer (score 1):

If we set aside the island bit, *across* suggests the goal is getting to the other side. *Through* suggests the goal lies within.

If the bar is in the middle of the restaurant, you walk through the restaurant to get to the bar. If the bar is off to the side of the restaurant, you walk across the restaurant to get to the bar.